# Meromorphic Function on a Riemann Surface

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

I have a question about an argument used in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in the excerpt below (or look up at pages 73/74):

[image]

In the proof we construct locally in $U$ a polynomial

$$F= \prod (t-f_i) =t^d +a_{n-1}t^{d-1} + ... + a_0 \in \mathcal{M}(U)[t]$$

with $a_j$ as elementary symmetric polynomials of the $f_i$ are moromorphic on $U$.

In order to glue these $F$ together to a polynomial in $\mathcal{M}(X)[t]$ we must check that the $a_i$ on the overlaps of two open sets $U, W$ coinside (then we can "glue" $F_U,F_W$ together).

I don't understand why the $F$ (resp the a_i$'s) must coinside on the overlaps. Does it depend on a choice, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, the $f_i$ agree on overlaps by construction, and the $a_i$ are just elementary symmetric polynomials in the $f_i$ like you said.

Comment: I should say that the $f_i$ agree up to permutation (which sheet you call the first sheet etc), but that ambiguity is killed by taking symmetric polynomials.

Comment: For $f \in \mathcal{M}(X),q \in Y, t \in \Bbb{C}$, $F(q,t) = \prod_{p \in \phi^{-1}(q)}(t - f (p))$. Then $q \mapsto F(q,t)$ is everywhere locally meromorphic $Y \to \Bbb{C}[t]$, because locally $F(q,t) = \prod_{j=1}^d (t-f \circ \psi_j(q)) $ where the $\psi_j$ are the local inverses of $\phi$. In general from local meromorphicity we'd need to look at monodromy to obtain global meromorphicity. Here $F(q,t)$ is obviously uniquely defined, so $q \mapsto F(q,t)$ is globally meromorphic $Y \to \Bbb{C}[t]$ and the claim about the algebraic-ness of $\mathcal{M}(X)/\phi^*\mathcal{M}(Y)$ follows.

Comment: When looking at how the analytic continuation over a closed curve permutes the $\psi_j$, this is the characterization of meromorphic functions in term of monodromy. Monodromy is the main point when constructing $\overline{\Bbb{C}(z)}$ as a field of locally meromorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}$ minus a few branch points.

Comment: @reuns:so if I try to draw a analogy to vector bundles the monodromy fulfills here essentially the role of "transition maps" which also uniquely determine the global object as a kind of "glueing plan"

Comment: $\log z$ is locally meromorphic on $0< |z|< 1$ but it has non-trivial monodromy